# Every time I open my preview screen or return back to it then the images in it takes 1-2 seconds to load image again

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a game preview screen where I have a stateless widget for scaffold and all and then a secondary stateless widget to show preview for each game. But when I open this preview page then all 3 of my preview images take sometime to load the image and when I tap the preview I can play the game and after returning from the game it again rebuild/ loads the preview images.

```
class Games extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Games",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0),),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GamePreviewScreen(index: 0,),
            GamePreviewScreen(index: 1,),
            GamePreviewScreen(index: 2,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Stateless widget for preview:-

```
class GamePreviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  String imagePath='';
  GamePreviewScreen({this.index,});
  String getPath()
  {
    if(index==0)
      return 'images/EgyptGame/preview.png';
    else if(index==1)
      return 'images/EgyptGame/preview.png';
    else
      return 'images/EgyptGame/preview.png';
  }
  openGame(BuildContext context)
  {
    if(index==0)
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePageForGame2()));
    else if(index==1)
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePageForGame2()));
    else
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePageForGame2()));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: (){openGame(context);},
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.cyan[200],width: 5),
        ),
        child: Image.asset(getPath(),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on your image size, dimensions and save it in jpg format it will load pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Either convert your widgets to `StatefulWidget` or add a `GlobalKey` to `Scaffold` in `Games` page and `GestureDetector` of `GamePreviewScreen`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a caching structure.
In addition, when using debug mode, a slower and more tiring experience is offered. This problem may disappear if you run your application in release mode.

Comment: When you run it in release mode you will know we are talking about the right thing.

Comment: I have other asset images as well working prefectly but only on this page am facing it so i don't think that release mode is the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try `flutter run --release` in the terminal maybe you are running your app in the debug mode. It's way slower if you run the app in this mode because it has some features

Comment: I have other asset images as well working prefectly but only on this page am facing it so i don't think that release mode is the answer.